# Read each line of a column of a file and execute grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep, echo

I have `file.txt` exemplary here:

```
This line contains ABC
This line contains DEF
This line contains GHI
```

and here the following `list.txt`:

```
contains ABC<TAB>ABC
contains DEF<TAB>DEF
```

Now I am writing a script that executes the following commands for each line of this external file `list.txt`:

1. take the string from **column 1** of `list.txt` and search in a third file `file.txt`
2. if the first command is positive, return the string from **column 2** of `list.txt`

So my `output.txt` is:

```
ABC
DEF
```

This is my code for grep/echo with putting the query/return strings manually:

```
if grep -i -q 'contains abc' file.txt
then
    echo ABC >output.txt
else
    echo -n
fi
if grep  -i -q 'contains def' file.txt
then
    echo DEF >>output.txt
else
    echo -n
fi
```

I have about 100 search terms, which makes the task laborious if done manually. So how do I include `while read line; do [commands]; done<list.txt` together with the commands about column1 and column2 inside that script?
I would like to use simple `grep`/`echo`/`awk`commands if possible.

Comment: First, read and store `column 1` and `column 2` of `list.txt` as arrays. Then you can `while read line` through `file.txt` only and perform commands.

Comment: column 1 on list.txt is just `contains`? did you mean that?

Comment: elaborate your input, does you `file.txt` contains exactly `This line contains ABC` or it was just written for denoting ?

Comment: @Inian `list.txt` contains a substring of `file.txt`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, `file.txt` contains exactly `This line contains ABC` and so on!

Comment: @ChiPak ok but I have zero experience with arrays :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2; next } {for (x in a) if (index($0, x)) {print a[x]}}     '   list.txt file.txt
ABC
DEF
```

For the lines of the first file (`FNR==NR`), read the key-value pairs to array `a`. Then for the lines of the second line, loop through the array, check if the key is found on the line, and if so, print the stored value. `index($0, x)` tries to find the contents of `x` from (the current line) `$0`. `$0 ~ x` would instead take `x` as a regex to match with.

---

If you want to  do it in the shell, starting a separate `grep` for each and every line of `list.txt`, something like this:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read k v ; do 
    grep -qFe "$k" file.txt && echo "$v"
done < list.txt
```

`read k v` reads a line of input and splits it (based on `IFS`) into `k` and `v`. 
`grep -F` takes the pattern as a fixed string, not a regex, and `-q` prevents it from outputting the matching line. `grep` returns true if any matching lines are found, so `$v` is printed if `$k` is found in file.txt.

Comment: thanks for your `awk` solution. However, I still try to understand the `grep`: I tried it with a slightly different command: `while IFS=$'\t' read k v ; do  if (($(grep -i '$k' file.txt | wc -l)>=2)); then echo "$k more than 2"; fi; done<list.txt` to see if a string from `list.txt` comes up more than twice in `file.txt`. Unfortunately, nothing is returned. Could you explain why?

Comment: @tobi, note the type of quotes you use, variables aren't expanded within single quotes, so `grep '$k'` will look for the literal string `$k`. Also, you can use `grep -c` instead of `grep | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and grep:

```
for text in `awk '{print $4}' file.txt `
do
  grep "contains $text" list.txt |awk -F $'\t' '{print $2}'
done
```

Comment: I think there is a mixup in the files. input for awk would be `list.txt`, input for grep should be `file.txt`